# using dynamic_cast with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, dynamic-cast

while implementing a template-based factory in C++, i have created the following `allocator` function to instantiate a given child class:

```
template<class ChildClass, class ParentClass>
ParentClass* allocator() {
   ChildClass *child  = new ChildClass();
   ParentClass*parent = dynamic_cast<ParentClass*>(child);
   if(NULL==parent) {
     delete child;
     return NULL;
   }
   return parent;
}
```

everything works fine, but when running the code through static code-analysis tools like [coverity](http://www.coverity.com/), the `delete child;` line is flagged as *logically dead code*.

the reason why i do the runtime-check is to assert, that `ChildClass` is derived from `ParentClass`.

now i understand, that during template expansion the compiler already knows whether `ChildClass` is derived from `ParentClass`, and that the `dynamic_cast` is only evaluated during run-time.

so the run-time check is logically dead code, if the `ChildClass` is indeed derived from the `ParentClass` (in which case the `dynamic_cast` will always return `non-NULL` if `ChildClass` has been successfully allocated).

**but** is there a way to ensure that `ChildClass` is derived from `ParentClass` during compile-time (template expansion time)?

afaik, templates and inheritance are unrelated in C++, but i might be missing something obvious.

### restrictions

unfortunately the code should compile on older compilers (e.g. the C++-implementation that comes with *Visual Studio 6*) which rules out any newer extension like `C++11`-features

Comment: If your compiler and library is C++11 capable, you can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point, however i'd like to be able to do legacy compilations of my code with *VisualStudio-6* (sic!), so it's not even `C++98`

Comment: You should clearly state those kind of restrictions in your question.

Comment: There are BOOST alternatives to the C++11 solution I posted. See my edit.

Comment: Your current implementation will throw `std::bad_alloc` on `new` if it can't allocate memory, not give a `nullptr`. you should use `new(std::nothrow) ChildClass();` if you want to get a `nullptr` on failure ;)

Comment: Think dynamic_cast only makes sense, when you want to cast to a child of the common base class, i.e. the other direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
constexpr bool is_base = std::is_base_of<ParentClass, ChildClass>::value;
```

You can use this inside a `static_assert` to signal a compiler error when `ChildClass` is not derived from `ParentClass`.

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<ParentClass, ChildClass>::value,
              "ParentClass is not base of ChildClass");
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can use [`boost::is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) and [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Answer (score 2):

If "Derived" inherits from "Base", then a pointer a "Derived" can be assigned to a pointer to "Base". I.e.:

```
void AssignToBase(Derived* derived) {
  Base* base = derived;
}
```

... the successful compilation of the above proves that "Derived" inherits from "Base". You can use this in conjunction with SFINAE and static assertions (whether in C++11 or using Boost's static assertion mechanism) to validate that the derived class inherits from the parent class. As juanchopanza notes, C++11 provides a simple std::is_base_of<> type traits class that you can use to test this inheritance relationship.

Comment: Regarding the return value, the OP is returning `parent` which will be either a valid pointer or `NULL`, so no bug.

Comment: @umläute, you're right. That being said, it would definitely be easier to read if there was an early "return nullptr" here.